# Timing on rollover jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add a `fadeTo()` function into this code so the rollover isn't instantaneous.

```
// JavaScript Document

function initRollovers() {
if (!document.getElementById) return

var aPreLoad = new Array();
var sTempSrc;
var aImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < aImages.length; i++) {      
    if (aImages[i].className == 'imgover') {
        var src = aImages[i].getAttribute('src');
        var ftype = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('.'), src.length);
        var hsrc = src.replace(ftype, '_o'+ftype);

        aImages[i].setAttribute('hsrc', hsrc);

        aPreLoad[i] = new Image();
        aPreLoad[i].src = hsrc;

        aImages[i].onmouseover = function() {
            sTempSrc = this.getAttribute('src');
            this.setAttribute('src', this.getAttribute('hsrc'));
        }   

        aImages[i].onmouseout = function() {
            if (!sTempSrc) sTempSrc = this.getAttribute('src').replace('_o'+ftype, ftype);
            this.setAttribute('src', sTempSrc);
        }
    }
}
}

window.onload = initRollovers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
// JavaScript Document
$(window).ready(function () {
initRollovers();
})

function initRollovers() {
if (!document.getElementById) return

var aPreLoad = new Array();
var sTempSrc;
var aImages = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < aImages.length; i++) {
    if (aImages[i].className == 'imgover') {
        var src = aImages[i].getAttribute('src');
        var ftype = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('.'), src.length);
        var hsrc = src.replace(ftype, '_o' + ftype);

        aImages[i].setAttribute('hsrc', hsrc);

        aPreLoad[i] = new Image();
        aPreLoad[i].src = hsrc;

        $(aImages[i]).mouseenter(function () {
            sTempSrc = this.getAttribute('src');
            sCurrent = this;
            $(sCurrent).fadeOut(function () {
                this.setAttribute('src', this.getAttribute('hsrc'));
                $(sCurrent).fadeIn();
            });

        })

        $(aImages[i]).mouseleave(function () {
            $(sCurrent).fadeOut(function () {
                if (!sTempSrc) sTempSrc = this.getAttribute('src').replace('_o' + ftype, ftype);
                this.setAttribute('src', sTempSrc);
                $(sCurrent).fadeIn();
            })


        })
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it didnt work when I implemented it

Comment: Can you provide me absolute url's of both the images.

Comment: im not sure what you mean but the my html is <div ID="dribbble"><img src="images/dribbble.png" class="dribbble"></div>

Comment: have you included jquery library in the page

Comment: Oh okay! Im not sure how to do that! I've downloaded a library and put it into my root folders and have linked it in my html but it doesn't seem to work